# angular2-material dateTimePicker dose not have time property

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker

i'm using angular2-material dateTimePicker but my problem it seems to only have the date class , and when i look around i only find the once that where implemented on angularJS and i don't know JS

Comment: Have you try to install this npm library?. npm install angular2-material-datepicker

Comment: yes i am using that but i think it only contains the date calendar and does not includes the time

Comment: Two months passed and there still doesn't seem to be a time-picker. Thendo, did you find any alternatives?

Comment: hi phil i couldn't get the material time/clock picker so i ended up using the bootstrap [clockpicker][1] which will need uses java script and just styled it to have a material like look / but you can also use the [primeng][2] one 


  [1]: https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/
  [2]: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar